# can't stop IIS on windows 8.1 tried everything, I'm trying to run WAMPSERVER

Tags: windows, iis, cmd, wampserver

basically I'm trying to create a simple website using WAMPSERVER, but I tried everty step, using windows feature turn on, cmd, but when I type localhost in firefox or IE, it still shows IIS, what should I do?

Comment: If you have no intention of using IIS then uninstall it and all its periferal tools

Answer (score 0):

If you use a WAMPSERVER on windows the IIS (Internet Information Services) feature should be turned off on your windows computer.

Comment: Well thats exactly what he has said, he is asking how to turn off IIS

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/

Do the reverse of this manual to remove it.